# implementing a trackbar that will change background color of form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

i would like to have a trackbar on my form that will correspond to the HUE of the color of the backgruond, given a range of 1 to 360, and another trackbar that will correspond to saturation of the color of the backgruond, within a range of 1 to 50.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `HSVtoRGB` procedure found [here](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=302304), you can hook both your `TrackBar` controls to the same event handler and use this code:

```
Private Sub tbHUE_Scroll(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tbHUE.Scroll, tbSaturation.Scroll
  Dim r, g, b As Integer
  HSVtoRGB(r, g, b, tbHUE.Value, tbSaturation.Value / 50, 255)
  BackColor = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b)
End Sub
```

Edit: Here is the corrected procedure since the one in the link doesn't really follow best practices:

```
Private Sub HSVtoRGB(ByRef Red As Integer, ByRef Green As Integer, ByRef Blue As Integer, ByVal Hue As Double, ByVal Sat As Double, ByVal Value As Integer)
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim f As Double, p As Double, q As Double, t As Double

  If Sat = 0 Then
    Red = Value
    Green = Value
    Blue = Value
    Exit Sub
  End If

  i = CInt(Hue) \ 60
  Hue = Hue / 60
  f = Hue - i
  p = Value * (1 - Sat)
  q = Value * (1 - Sat * f)
  t = Value * (1 - Sat * (1 - f))

  Select Case i
    Case 0
      Red = Value
      Green = CInt(t)
      Blue = CInt(p)
    Case 1
      Red = CInt(q)
      Green = Value
      Blue = CInt(p)
    Case 2
      Red = CInt(p)
      Green = Value
      Blue = CInt(t)
    Case 3
      Red = CInt(p)
      Green = CInt(q)
      Blue = Value
    Case 4
      Red = CInt(t)
      Green = CInt(p)
      Blue = Value
    Case 5
      Red = Value
      Green = CInt(p)
      Blue = CInt(q)
  End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: julien thank you very much. i am having trouble and getting errors because the code on the webpage is not .NET. for the following: Private Sub UnRGB(ByVal Color As OLE_COLOR, ByRef r, ByRef g, ByRef b) ------- it doesnt know what OLE_COLOR is and for the r, g, and b, it says Error  All parameters must be explicitly typed if any of them are explicitly typed

Comment: now i am getting Error 4 Operator 'And' is not defined for types 'System.Drawing.Color' and 'Integer'.

Comment: Ha yes, the procedure in the link assumes you have 'Option Explicit' off, I'll include the code to make it easier

Answer (score 1):

*Julien has a good answer, but this will come up in searches, so lots of links always helps :-)*

Bob Powell also has some HSL code in his [RGB and HSL Colour Space Conversions](https://web.archive.org/web/20141023005253/http://bobpowell.net/RGBHSB.aspx).

And, (this one's in c# so probably won't help so much), Chris Jackson has some [HSB code](https://web.archive.org/web/20190113214810/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cjacks/2006/04/12/converting-from-hsb-to-rgb-in-net/) that looks reasonable. The vb.net port that was linked is, uhm, notsogood, it has issues with option strict turned on. Not insurmountable, but not copypaste ready either